# How to exclude rows from count

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to make a report in MS Access that tracks late appointments and having trouble with a simple query. My SQL is rusty but here's what I have:

```
SELECT Date, COUNT([DRC 1]) AS Delays
FROM Schedule
GROUP BY Date
HAVING (((Date) Between [Start Date] And [End Date]));
```

This counts all appointments for each day within a given range and organizes them by date, but I want to exclude appointments that started on time. Column [DRC 1] contains a number code from another table with different reasons why the appointment was late. Code '0' means 'No Delay'. I've tried several things but none have worked. Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Here is an example of my table for reference.

```
+————————+——————————+———————————————+————————————————+————————+—————————+—————+
|Date    |Name      |Sched. Time-In |Sched. Time-Out |Time-In |Time-Out |DRC 1|
+————————+——————————+———————————————+————————————————+————————+—————————+—————+
|2/3/2020|Doe, John |12:00 PM       |12:30 PM        |12:25 PM|12:49 PM |1    |
|2/3/2020|Ross, Bob |1:00 PM        |1:30 PM         |1:07 PM |1:34 PM  |2    |
|2/3/2020|Doe, Jane |2:00 PM        |2:30 PM         |2:00 PM |2:27 PM  |0    |
+————————+——————————+———————————————+————————————————+————————+—————————+—————+
```

It **SHOULD** be as simple as adding a WHERE clause, but it seems to just ignore it and counts all the rows anyway. I've tried:

```
WHERE [DRC 1] <> 0
WHERE [DRC 1] != 0
WHERE [DRC 1] > 0
WHERE [DRC 1] <> '0' (in case the column wasn't an INT)
WHERE [DRC 1] != '0' (")
```

Even the native methods in MS Access have failed me. I'm starting to think the issue might be some oddity within Access.

Comment: "...but I want to exclude appointments that started on time" - then you should add a `where` clause.

Comment: Looks like a ``where DRC <> 0`` after ``FROM Schedule`` should be enough but it would be intersting to see your data to make sure

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide some data? But I think

```
SELECT Date, COUNT([DRC 1]) AS Delays
FROM Schedule
WHERE DRC  <> 0
GROUP BY Date
HAVING (((Date) Between [Start Date] And [End Date]));
```

should cut it!

Answer (score 0):

First, filter on the date *before* aggregating rather than after.

Second, you can filter on the "late" codes in the `WHERE` as well.

So:

```
SELECT Date, COUNT(*) AS Delays
FROM Schedule
WHERE Date Between [Start Date] And [End Date] AND
      [DRC 1] <> 0
GROUP BY Date;
```

If a date has no delays, it will not be in the result set.  If you want all days with `0` counts, then:

```
SELECT Date, SUM(IIF([DRC 1] <> 0, 1, 0)) AS Delays
FROM Schedule
WHERE Date Between [Start Date] And [End Date] 
GROUP BY Date
```

Comment: Very good point about days without delays not being shown in the count. I tried both your queries but no change in my results. I'm becoming convinced it's Access that's screwing with me...

Comment: @Ethameshep . . . Make sure your dates are actually dates and not strings.

Comment: I checked and the column uses the only data type Access offers for date and time, so presumably DATETIME